# The type RowMapper is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments<class>

Tags: spring-mvc

```
public Emp getEmpById(int id){  
    String sql="select * from Emp99 where id=?";  
    return template.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{id},new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Emp>(Emp.class));  
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes,its a question